# Code igniter not matching my [a-z] route

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this url which displays a list of products and is managed by a controller called category_listing:

```
http://localhost:8888/shop/mens/trainers/
```

I've added pagination to this page using uri segment 4 so the url ends up looking like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/shop/mens/trainers/2
```

I also want to have a route that allows the user to view the product by visiting this url:

```
http://localhost:8888/shop/mens/trainers/a-trainer-product-here
```

This is managed by a controller called product_listing.

So I created a route:

```
$route['shop/(:any)/(:any)/[a-z]'] = 'product/product_listing/$1/$2/$3';
```

which I hoped would allow me to match all product urls whilst ignoring the urls with pagination indexes in them. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working. When I visit a link with a product in the url, the page (which should be using the product_listing controller) is still trying to call the category_listing controller.

Any ideas? I was wondering if perhaps the hyphens in the product name part of the url (a-trainer-product-here) were causing issues with the [a-z] part of the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you are using can only match letters from a to z, and it only match once, it won't match "-"
so instead of:

```
 $route['shop/(:any)/(:any)/[a-z]']
```

you could try:

```
 $route['shop/(:any)/(:any)/([a-z-]*)']
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The `[a-z]` alone is only matching one charachter. You probably want to add a modifier like `+` for one or more or `*` for zero or more. Your pattern also indicates that you want to capture that last segment too (you have `$3` in your replacement) and your example slug have `-`s in it so the plain `[a-z]` would only match the "a" in front of it.

Combining all these, i think you would want to write:

```
$route['shop/(:any)/(:any)/([-a-z]*)'] = 'product/product_listing/$1/$2/$3';
```

This will match zero or more length slugs, captures them for in `$3` and allow `-`s too.
I would also consider using simply a third `(:any)` there, depending on how you create these slugs.

Comment: ([-a-z]+) this won't match the first url above.

Comment: Oh, mea culpa. Thanks, fixed.